# Keep column with id when calculating closeness for a list of dataframes in tnet

Tags: r, list

I am working with the `closeness_w` function of R's `tnet` (https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/tnet/versions/3.0.14/topics/closeness_w).

I have two data frames, `df1` and `df2`. When I compute the `closeness_w` for each data frame, R keeps the unique id which is in column i (and renames it "node"). The output shows the "closeness" and "n.closeness" results.

However, if I do this for `mylist` of the data frames, R drops the i column and does not show the "n.closeness" results. For `mylist`, I am trying to get the "node", "closeness" and "n.closeness" results just as I get them when doing the calculation on each individual data frame.

Does anybody know how to do this?

`df1`

```
i   <- c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6)
j   <- c(2, 3, 1, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 2, 2, 6, 5)
w   <- c(4, 2, 4, 4, 1, 2, 2, 4, 1, 2, 1, 1)
df1 <- data.frame(i, j, w)
closeness_w(df1)
```

`df2`

```
i   <- c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 7)
j   <- c(2, 3, 4, 3, 7, 5, 1, 6, 2, 2, 1, 5)
w   <- c(4, 2, 4, 4, 1, 2, 2, 4, 1, 2, 1, 1)
df2 <- data.frame(i, j, w)
closeness_w(df2)
```

`mylist`

```
mylist <- list(df1, df2)
mylist_output <- lapply(mylist, function(x) closeness_w(x)[, "closeness", drop = FALSE])
mylist_output
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do

```
mylist_output <- lapply(mylist, function(x) closeness_w(x)[, "closeness", drop = FALSE])
```

you are specifying to only return a `data.frame` with the column 'closeness'. If you want to keep all columns, simply do:

```
mylist_output <- lapply(mylist, function(x) closeness_w(x))
```

or

```
mylist_output <- lapply(mylist,closeness_w)
```

Hope this helps.